# No internet connection inside Docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker, internet-connection

I cannot execute any command requiring internet connection inside any Docker container.

Works:

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/echo 'Hello world'
```

Does not work:

```
docker run ubuntu apt-get update

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Similar with `pip` and `ping`.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and not using firewall or corporate proxy server and have tried to restart Docker. Not using docker-machine or boot2docker.

Comment: whats the `docker network ls` output?

Comment: I'm assuming your docker host hast internet access.

Comment: the answer was to fully reboot Docker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Got answer on SuperUser:](https://superuser.com/questions/1130898/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers)

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

"It will force docker to recreate the bridge and reinit all the network rules"

Answer (score 0):

In my case only deleteting the docker0 interface wasn't enough,j I had to delete the br interfaces (see `ip link`) as well.

For the Linux users out there that use systemd:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
if ! [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then
   echo "Run as root please."
   exit 1
fi

# not sure if this is needed
iptables -t nat -F

# stop docker
systemctl stop docker

# stop the `br-...` interfaces.
ip link | awk -F': ' '/: br-/ {print $2}' | xargs -I % ifconfig % down
# ... and remove them
ip link | awk -F': ' '/: br-/ {print $2}' | xargs brctl delbr

# stop the docker0 interface
ifconfig docker0 down
# ... and remove it
brctl delbr docker0

# start docker again, this will re-create the docker0 interface.
systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following sequence:

1. Install `connman` if not installed earlier:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install connman -y
```

2. Follow [this solution](https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-no-network-when-running-a-container-in-arch-linux/5494/6)

```
sudo nano /etc/connman/main.conf
```

3. Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```