# Docker Container no internet Ubuntu 22 fresh install

Tags: docker, networking, connection, ubuntu-22.04

The problem: My docker-compose script can't connect to the outbound internet.
Currently i am on a Ubuntu 22.04.2 System. On my other server Ubuntu 20 the same script works. Therefore my configuration for docker must be wrong.

In my docker-compose script i want to create with letsencrypt a new certificate but when communicating with letsencrypt i get errors.

Running budybox with ping:

```
docker run --rm -it busybox ping -c 3 acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
```

Results in:

```
ping: bad address 'acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org'
```

But when i run in network host it works:

```
docker run --rm -it --network host busybox ping -c 3 acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
```

Result:

```
PING acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org (172.65.32.248): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.65.32.248: seq=0 ttl=58 time=0.859 ms
64 bytes from 172.65.32.248: seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.745 ms
^C
--- acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
```

This is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  outer:
    container_name: outer
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - DHPARAM_GENERATION=false
    logging:
      driver: local #or "none" or "local"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro # allow to read running dockers
      - ./extraVolumes/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./extraVolumes/vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./extraVolumes/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file: .env
    environment:
    ### ToDo: Change to your e-mail address
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=${EMAIL}
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=outer
    volumes_from:
      - outer
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./extraVolumes/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - ./extraVolumes/vhosts:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      - ./acme:/etc/acme.sh
    restart: always
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

  app:
    container_name: outer_app
    image: jwilder/whoami
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/ping/
      - VIRTUAL_DEST=/
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

  redirect:
    image: morbz/docker-web-redirect
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/
      - VIRTUAL_DEST=/
      - REDIRECT_TARGET=${MYHOST}/homepage/ # Just /homepage without ending with a / will result in infinite redirects
      # For more see: https://serverfault.com/questions/821997/nginx-reverse-proxy-too-many-redirections
      # Also the - VIRTUAL_PATH=/ping/ must end with a / too
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

  redirect_catch:
    container_name: redirect_catch
    image: jwilder/whoami
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${MYHOST}
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/homepage/homepage/
      - VIRTUAL_DEST=/
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    name: topDomainProxy
```

I configured my .env accordingly, replaced values with OMITED.

```
MYHOST=OMITED
EMAIL=OMITED
PATH_TO_CERT=./
PATH_TO_KEY=./
```

When running my compose file:

```
letsencrypt_1     | [Wed Jun 14 20:15:07 UTC 2023] Please refer to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code: 7
letsencrypt_1     | [Wed Jun 14 20:15:07 UTC 2023] Can not init api for: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory.
letsencrypt_1     | [Wed Jun 14 20:15:08 UTC 2023] Registering account: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
letsencrypt_1     | [Wed Jun 14 20:15:11 UTC 2023] Please refer to https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for error code: 7
letsencrypt_1     | [Wed Jun 14 20:15:11 UTC 2023] Could not get nonce, let's try again.
```

What can i do, where is my problem?
I cant change my Ubuntu...

I already tried:

- reinstalling docker
- ip forward
- daemon.json to configure
- and a lot of other stack overflow answers.

Already tried: [No internet connection inside Docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828185/no-internet-connection-inside-docker-containers)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394060/home-internet-not-working-with-ubuntu not working

Comment: So on a fresh Ubuntu 22.04. it does not work but on a Ubuntu 20.04. and debian this works.

Comment: Look here, this worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440642/2848289